# DTEXEC.exe for running an SSIS 2013 package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, command-line, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2013 and I'm trying to run a .dtsx via the command line using dtexec.

If I use: `dtexec.exe /file "C:\MyFolder\sub folder \the ssis Package .dtsx"`
will return:

> Couldn't load package because of error 0XC0010014. This occurs when
>   CPackage:: Load from XML fails.

If, however I use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /file "C:\MyFolder\sub folder \the ssis Package .dtsx"
```

I can see that part of the task is running, since it's warning me about trimming two columns in a task I have (the same warning I was getting in SSIS, but everything worked).

> Warning: 2016-01-28 13:41:49.53    Code: 0x802092A7    Source: Data
>   Flow Task OLE DB Destination [99]    Description: Truncation may occur
>   due to inserting data from data flow column  "ISSUER_OTHER_NAME" with
>   a length of 124 to database column "ISSUER_OTHER_NAME"  with a length
>   of 68.

After that, I am getting:

> Error: 2016-01-28 13:41:49.68    Code: 0xC000F427    Source: Execute
>   Process Task    Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL
>   Server Data Tools you must install Execute Process Task of Integration
>   Services or higher. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_SUCCESS (0).

It looks like others had this on a different host without any Integration Services installed. But I am using it in the same place and even the warnings are working since I can see the names of some columns.
My guess is the version of dtexec.exe which as you can see I am taking it from the `120\dts\binn\` folder. 
Is this the right one to use for my SSIS? 
Please see below my SSIS version and SQL Server
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I developed an SSIS package in VS2013 and had a lot of compatibility issues deploying against SQL 2012. The consistent solution that worked for me was to install SQL 2014 and use that version of DTExec to publish to SQL 2012.

Comment: I would, but i am not allowed to. I can work only with what I have

Answer (score 0):

Try running the 32 bit version from the command line using the version from the x86 folder instead of the 64bit version, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\ .

Comment: please read my question again. This is what I was doing. Find it under "however, if i use: ...*code* "

Answer (score -3):

This is a license check - you need to install at least the Integration Services component of SQL Server 2012 on your machine.

Comment: I cannot make any modifications to what I have. I can only use the programs in the list. The funny thing is, there is another pc with the same things installed on which it works. But not on mine. I need a workaround using what i have

Comment: Please read the comment again. There is another pc with the same things installed on which it works. I don't know why and I'm trying to find a way to make it work on mine